# Tensorflow Sequence to Sequence CustomHelper

Tags: python, tensorflow, helper, seq2seq

There are limited amount of documentation on Sequence to Sequence CustomHelper

`helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.CustomHelper(initialize_fn = initialize_fn,sample_fn = sample_fn, next_inputs_fn = next_inputs_fn)`

in Tensorflow.

Would anyone explain the inputs of the Custom-helper, in terms of the input data

`X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size x time_steps x features])`

and encoder,

`encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size)`

`initial_state = encoder_cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)`

and/or possibly

`rnn_output, rnn_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(encoder_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)`
?